# Loop through a href tags in a li ul starting from a div using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

How do I loop through every a href element and then get the text from the href starting from div Foo.

Basically I want to loop through values Hello, World, Acc, Sale, etc.

```
<div id="Foo">
   <div class="Moo">
      <ul>
         <li>
            <a href="http://www.test.com/b5">Hello</a>
         </li>
         <li>
            <a href="http://www.test.com/b6">World</a>
         </li>
         <li>
            <a href="http://www.test.com/b7">Acc</a>
         </li>
         <li>
            <a href="http://www.test.com/b8">Sale</a>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

AAAAH WHAT THE HELL THIS LANGUAGE IS DRIVING ME NUTS. How come this doesn't work? I'm basically pointing at the objects and saying loop through every A.

```
$('#Foo').find('.Moo ul li').find('a').each(function(){
   alert($(this).text);
});
```

This doesn't work either.

```
$('#Foo.Moo ul li a').each(function(){
   alert($(this).text);
});
```

nor this, they just keep returning javascript instead of the value of the a tag.

```
('#Foo .Moo ul li a').each(function(){  
   alert($(this).text);
});
```

Comment: You're just missing `()` after the function name to call the function. This is basic programming syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like

```
$("#Foo .Moo ul li a").each(function(){
     alert($(this).text());
});
```

from your code it may like

```
$('#Foo').find('.Moo ul li').find('a').each(function(){
   alert($(this).text());
});
```

It would be like `.text()` not like `.text` And proper your html like

```
<div id="Foo">
<div class="Moo">
    <ul>
        <li>
        <a href="http://www.test.com/b5">Hello</a>
        <ul>                
            <li>
            <a href="http://www.test.com/b6">World</a>
            </li>
            <ul>
                <li>
                <a href="http://www.test.com/b7">Acc</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                <a href="http://www.test.com/b8">Sale</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
           </ul>
           </li>
         </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: his html is not valid. you solution is not gonna help

Comment: man I really need a super fast editor that corrects this stuff. Netbeans takes too long to open.

Comment: Just keep it running all the time, like I do with PhpStorm.

Answer (score 1):

Your html is not valid

```
<div id="Foo">
    <div class="Moo">
        <ul>
            <li>
            <a href="http://www.test.com/b5">Hello</a>
            <ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                <a href="http://www.test.com/b6">World</a>
                <ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    <a href="http://www.test.com/b7">Acc</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    <a href="http://www.test.com/b8">Sale</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

this might be the cause.

fix it and then re-ask.

then you can do this :

```
$('#Foo .Moo ul li a').each(function(){
   alert($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: But your JS is still wrong. text is not a property its a function.

Comment: @mohkhan yup. (that's what happends when you paste too fast) :)

Answer (score 0):

You HTML is invalid, so this doesnt work. Remove the unwanted `<ul>` in the middle:

```
<div id="Foo">
    <div class="Moo">
        <ul>
            <li>
<a href="http://www.test.com/b5">Hello</a>

            </li>
            <li>
<a href="http://www.test.com/b6">World</a>

            </li>
            <li>
<a href="http://www.test.com/b7">Acc</a>

            </li>
            <li>
<a href="http://www.test.com/b8">Sale</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

You could then use `map()` to iterate over the `<a>` and get the text, the store it in an array.

```
var aText = $("#Foo a").map(function () {
    return this.innerHTML;
}).get();
alert(JSON.stringify(aText)); //not needed. You could access that text like this : aText[i] where i = 0|1|2
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/WG2Hg/